# ApacheのRequire ディレクティブ(ユーザー名とipの関係)について教えてください

Tags: apache

```
  <RequireAll>
    Require ip 192.168
    <RequireAny>
        Require group admin
        Require ip 192.168.1
    </RequireAny>
  </RequireAll>
```

apacheの設定を勉強していたら、このような設定が出てきました。
これはwebサーバーに接続するにはadminグループでなおかつ192.168.1系のIPを持つPCでないとアクセスできないことを意味しているそうなのですが、いまいちよくわからないのはIPとグループが紐づいている点です。

１、例えばLAN環境だとして、これはapacheの入っているwebサーバーの入っているPCにadminグループのユーザでssh接続し、その後webサーバにアクセスしたのか、それともwebサーバーが192.168.1.2だとしてクライアントとして192.168.1.3からアクセスしたのかどちらなんでしょう？後者の場合だとadminグループに所属することがそもそもできませんよね？

２、よくbashのプロンプトではhoge@hostnameのようにユーザ名とホスト名が同時に表示されていますが、考えてみたらホスト名はNICが複数あった場合ホスト名の部分だけ変更できるんでしょうか？

かなり初歩的な質問ですみません。ユーザとホストについて何か根本的な勘違いをしている気がしています。どうかよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `RequireAll` : 全ての条件を満たせば真
- `RequireAny` : 1つ以上の条件を満たせばば真
- `RequireNone` : いずれも満たさなければ真

ご質問の内容ですと、「`192.168.` で始まるIPかつadmin グループ」の場合と、「`192.168.1`で始まるIP」の場合にアクセスできるいう意味になると思います。

ここで言うグループとはなんぞや？という点ですが、Apacheにはベーシック認証やダイジェスト認証などの、認証機能があり、それらで認証されたユーザのグループです。

詳しいことはApache httpd のリファレンスやチュートリアルなどを読んでみて 確認してみてください。
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ja/mod/mod_authz_core.html
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ja/howto/auth.html